# I am connected to Wifi but I can’t access the internet

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking

Very simply put. I am connected to the internet. Applications Cus as Telegram Work. However I can’t seem to be able to browse the net. I have tried restarting my computer, renewing my winsock and resetting my dns. I can’t seem to connect.

Comment: try ping 8.8.8.8.

Comment: @AungMyat I have tried it. It is successful

Answer (score 1):

Might be an issue with your ISP DNS service. Configure your network settings to use Google Public DNS by adding IP addresses 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4 as your DNS servers.

Answer (score 0):

Run Windows built-in network troubleshooter tool.

[image]

Please boot into your Windows 10 check the wireless network driver:

1. Right click the device manager.
2. Expand the Network adapters.
3. Check that wireless network driver status.
4. If it's not working fine, right click it to uninstall it.
5. Click Action-> Scan for hardware changes to reinstall it again.

If the issue persists, run these commands with administrator to reset the TCP/IP:

netsh winsock reset catalog

netsh int ipv4 reset reset.log

netsh int ipv6 reset reset.log

Answer (score 0):

Check if you are connected to other internet sharing devices.

This problem arises very often in situations where two internet providing devices are connected to the laptop. They may not be providing internet, but your device will get configured to use both of them, which ends up causing a clash.

For example, your laptop may be connected to a router via an Ethernet cable, but then, it may be connected to a wifi hotspot too, and that will definitely cause a problem.